# where does go data written to file descriptor that was never opened

Tags: file-descriptors, strace, ipc

I have output captured by following command:

```
$ strace -f -e trace=process,socketpair,open,close,dup,dup2,read,write -o rsync.log rsync -avcz --progress src/ dst/
```

it is a bit long so I've uploaded it [here](http://www.filedropper.com/rsync). Now I want to do some analysis on this file.

Following output shows spawned processes/threads using `clone` syscall:

```
# SPAWNED PROCESSES/THREADS
$ grep 'clone(' rsync.log | awk '{print $1 " -> " $NF}'
1399 -> 1400
1400 -> 1401
```

Following output shows that most times data were `write`n to file descriptor with number `4`:

```
# PID, FD, NO OF CALLING WRITE SYSCALL
$ cat <(grep 'write(' rsync.log | egrep -v 'unfinished|resumed') <(paste <(grep write rsync.log | grep unfinished) <(grep write rsync.log | grep resumed)) | cut -d',' -f1 | sed 's%write(%%' | awk '{a[$0]++}END{print "PID  FD COUNT"; for(i in a){print i " " a[i]}}'
PID  FD COUNT
1399  4 1622
1400  1 7
1401  3 307
1401  4 7
1399  1 15
```

Following output shows that the `4` descriptor was never opened using `open` syscall (1 is STDOUT so I assume no need to open this FD):

```
# LIST OF FILE DESCRIPTORS THAT WAS OPEN
$ grep 'open(' rsync.log | awk 'BEGIN {FS=" = "} {print $NF}' | grep '^[0-9]\+$' | sort | uniq
0
3
6
```

Two questions:

I. If `4` descriptor was not `open`ed where does those data go, and how is possible that `rsync` worked as expected?:

```
$ grep 'write(4' rsync.log | head
1399  write(4, "\37\0\0\0", 4 <unfinished ...>
1399  write(4, "I\0\0\7\5(\1.\0\0\0W}%i\360\220\261\177\21\370A\0\0\0\203\347\6vbox"..., 77 <unfinished ...>
1401  write(4, "\4\0\0\7\376\377\377\377", 8) = 8
1399  write(4, "\177\301\0\7\3\n\200\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\177\377\354\226C\214.\0\260"..., 49539) = 49539
1399  write(4, "\2\301\0\7\177\377a\353\35\2433\1\332m\301\330\266\315\216\3557\352\330\266m\333\366\33\333\266;v"..., 49414) = 49414
1399  write(4, "\21\302\0\7\177\377\236mTNG\356\304\376u\237\214\275\310\300*\317\264\221W\372\340\307\36\345%\330"..., 49685 <unfinished ...>
1399  write(4, "\360\300\0\7\177\377\27W\357\24$\f\23,\v\216\355\371\306\266m\333\266m\333\266m\333\266m\333\266"..., 49396 <unfinished ...>
1399  write(4, "\223\301\0\7\177\377D\214# D\304\2\25xA\fY\310U\201Q*e\25\235\20\213\v\320~\331"..., 49559 <unfinished ...>
1399  write(4, "\370\300\0\7\177\377l\275cs.\0\27$\30\334\330\266}c\333\266m\333\266\235<\261m\333\266m"..., 49404 <unfinished ...>
1399  write(4, "\20\301\0\7\177\377\25\255\252Q\223\340\244w3\247\252\322Z\235\310\2424g\330\274\354\3150\237B\26"..., 49428) = 49428
```

II. Can I somehow also get data (corresponding lines) that were transferred between processes e.g.: from `1399` to `1400` or from `1399` to `1401` etc. (if there are any)?

Thank you

Comment: You'll find 3 and 4 created by `socketpair(PF_LOCAL, SOCK_STREAM, 0, [3, 4])` which return 2 file descriptors in the last arg.

Answer (score 0):

Data written to a file descriptor that was never opened does not go anywhere. The `write` system call fails with `EBADF` (bad file descriptor).

But as [meuh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/119298/meuh) [remarked](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/291422/where-does-go-data-written-to-file-descriptor-that-was-never-opened#comment510128_291422), `open` is not the only way to open a file. There's also `pipe` to create a pair of pipe ends, `socketpair` to create a pair of sockets that talk to each other, `socket` and `accept` to create sockets that talk to a remote address, etc. (Not to mention file types that you can't `write` to, such as directories, inotify event queues, etc.)